# Angular abstract REST service

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an abstract service that will access a REST API.

A simplified version of my abstract service is this:

```
    export abstract class BaseApiService<T>
    {
        protected endpoint;

        constructor(protected http: Http, protected authentication: AuthenticationService)
        {
        }

        public getItems(): Observable<T[]>
        {
            return this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}/all`, this.authentication.httpHeader)
                .map(res => res.json());
        }
}
```

And a sample implementation would be:

```
    export class AssociationKeyService extends BaseApiService<AssociationKey>
    {
        constructor(http: Http, authenticationService: AuthenticationService)
        {
            super(http, authenticationService);

            this.endpoint = apiEndpoint + '/associationkeys';
        }  
    }
```

If I run the application with the abstract service in the code, it works, but I'm not using the class obviously.

When I add the inherited class and add it to my `index.ts`, the application does not run anymore. I'm not even instantiating the service, I only add it to the `index.ts`. Here's the `index.ts`:

```
    // start:ng42.barrel
    export * from './user.service';
    export * from './association-key.service';
    export * from './base-api.service';
    // end:ng42.barrel
```

Then when I run the application I get the following error and it doesn't start:

```
    core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
        at webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/modules/corporative-manager/services/api-services/association-key.service.ts.__extends (http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:1036:68)
        at http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:1052:5
        at Object.../../../../../src/app/modules/corporative-manager/services/api-services/association-key.service.ts (http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:1059:2)
        at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:30)
        at Object.../../../../../src/app/modules/corporative-manager/services/api-services/index.ts (http://localhost:4200/0.chunk.js:1104:83)
        at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:30)
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Is there anything wrong with the abstract logic I'm trying to implement?

Comment: What does your index.ts file look like? It looks to me like it can't find your `BaseApiService`, possibly needs to be imported in the `AssociationKeyService` or the `index.ts` file.

Comment: watch out there is no res.json() in the> 4.3 version

Comment: @SimplyComplexable I edited the question to add the contents of my `index.ts`

Comment: @Whisher What would be the correct way of doing this now? Tried to find something about this change but I didn't find anything...

Comment: @SimplyComplexable you hinted me the answer. It wasn't finding my `BaseApiService`. I just find out that the order of the imports actually matters in the `index.ts`. I moved the import for the base service to the top of the file and it worked.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http like data['results']

Comment: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Comment: https://netbasal.com/a-taste-from-the-new-angular-http-client-38fcdc6b359b